# Pytest: run a function at the end of the tests

Tags: python, pytest

I would like to run a function at the end of **all** the tests.

A kind of global teardown function.

I found an example [here](https://gist.github.com/inklesspen/4555229) and some clues [here](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html) but it doesn't match my need. It runs the function at the beginning of the tests. I also saw the function `pytest_runtest_teardown()`, but it is called after each test.

Plus: if the function could be called only if all the tests passed, it would be great.

Comment: `pytest_unconfigure` seems to do the job, but maybe someone will come up with a better idea

Comment: To make your fixture run some function at the end, you should use `request.addfinalizer(tear_down_function)`. To make it run at the end of hole session, but not every test case - specify exact scope as `@pytest.fixture(scope="session")`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I found:

```
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    """ whole test run finishes. """
```

`exitstatus` can be used to define which action to run. [pytest docs about this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish)

Comment: Can I access other fixtures from `session`?

Comment: note that for this to work, the function must be declared in `conftest.py`

Answer (score 28):

To run a function at the end of all the tests, use a pytest fixture with a ["session" scope](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session). Here is an example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def cleanup(request):
    """Cleanup a testing directory once we are finished."""
    def remove_test_dir():
        shutil.rmtree(TESTING_DIR)
    request.addfinalizer(remove_test_dir)
```

The `@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)` bit adds a [pytest fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#fixture-scopes) which will run once every test session (which gets run every time you use `pytest`). The `autouse=True` tells pytest to run this fixture automatically (without being called anywhere else).

Within the `cleanup` function, we define the `remove_test_dir` and use the `request.addfinalizer(remove_test_dir)` line to tell pytest to run the `remove_test_dir` function once it is done (because we set the scope to "session", this will run once the entire testing session is done).

Comment: A disadvantage of using `addfinalizer` is that output is captured, whereas output is displayed normally when using `pytest_sessionfinish`

Comment: If pytest runs on multiples files, will this run end all the files's session is completed?

Comment: seeing this and the numbe of great ways to finalize with and without context makes me miss python.   jest is super annoying.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `atexit` module calling it at the end of the module as follows:

```py
atexit.register(report)
```

---

If you want to report something at the end of all the test you need to add a report funtion as follows:

```py
import atexit

def report(report_dict=report_dict):
    print("THIS IS AFTER TEST...")
    for k, v in report_dict.items():
        print(f"item for report: {k, v}")

atexit.register(report)
```

Comment: this is good when you want to print something to stdout and want it to go at the very end, after pytest's own report.